# GASでのトリガー設定方法(起動失敗の通知)について

Tags: google-apps-script

GASのトリガー設定について教えてください。
時間や起動するスクリプトをして、実際動作しましたが、
トリガー設定時に「起動失敗の通知」の設定がわからないことに気づきました。

私が見つけられないだけで、設定方法はあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GASによる「起動失敗の通知」設定ができないことがわかりました。